# Set different background colors for cardView in order of odd and even

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Want to set different background colors for odd and even cardview for recyclerview. Trying in onBindViewHolder method of Adapter class.

class NotificationAdapter(private val notifications: List) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationViewHolder>() {

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotificationViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_notification, parent, false)
    return NotificationViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotificationViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.txtTitle.text = notifications[position]

    if(position.isEven)
        it.root.setBackgroundColor(context.colorRes(R.color.sponsor_even_color))
    else
        it.root.setBackgroundColor(context.colorRes(R.color.sponsor_odd_color))

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return notifications.size
}

class NotificationViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    var txtTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notification_title)
    var txtDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notification_description)
}
```

}

Found the error:"Unresolved reference: it"

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: Unresolved reference: it

Comment: Found this error --> Unresolved reference: it

Comment: try change `it.root` to `holder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like:

```
class NotificationViewHolder(...){
   var cardView: CardView = = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView)
   //....
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotificationViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.txtTitle.text = notifications[position]

    if(position.isEven)
       holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(....)
    else
       holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(....)
}
```

And use the method [**`setCardBackgroundColor`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView#setCardBackgroundColor(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) instead of `setBackgroundColor`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
     if(position.isEven){
         .setCardBackgroundColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.context, R.color.red)}
     else{
        .setCardBackgroundColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.context, R.color.green)
       }
```

If someone still gets the white color instead of the color he picked, just change the emulator you working on, that's works for me